# Automatically mount network drives on login of any user without hard-coded network password?

Tags: windows, networking

Apologies if the title is a bit difficult to understand, but maybe I can clear things up here.

I'm in the difficult position where I've been tasked with setting up what we used to call 'Roaming Profiles' for my company's users. I'm dealing with an external IT company, and I'm completely stuck with the whole Office 365 / Azure AD stuff because of it.

The external IT company has advised that the easiest way to set up roaming profiles in this day and age is by syncing user's files with OneDrive. Since any user can login on any PC, OneDrive should begin copying the few files they'll have stored on their desktop and such to the PC they login on, and theoretically they won't see too much of a difference in regards to their user experience regardless of the computer they're on. Active Directory handles their emails and such, so that seems like the way to go.

However, our small business has a NAS that users need to access too. Unfortunately for me, this NAS can only hook into the old-school local Active Directory servers, not the Azure one. Therefore, I'm stuck with seporate users for the NAS and Active Directory.

So fine, I can deal with that. The problem is, we need network drives from this NAS to be mapped. When a user logs on for the first time on a new machine, it needs to immediately ask them for their NAS credentials and map the appropriate drives.

So I'm really after one of two solutions as far as I can tell, however if anybody has any other suggestions that may work, that would be awesome. The way I see it, either I work out some method of mounting all the drives *first*, and asking for credentials when you user first tries to open the drive, or I start a program that asks for the user's credentials first and maps the drives with `net use [drive]: [\\servername\share] /user:[input from program] [password from program]`.

I've successfully got a program that does the latter working, and I've stored it on a publicly accessible network location, however I can't work out a way of starting it at every login regardless of the user. I tried the startup folder and task scheduler - the first didn't fire at all, and the latter only fires on the account that the task was created with.

Additionally, the program brings up a 'Do you trust this file' warning each time you open it, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Can you add Azure users to a group in your regular AD? If so use a group to setup permissions? The warning as well as startup not working is probably due to your group policies. [Roaming Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-roaming-user-profiles) are also a bit more involved than just putting some stuff on OneDrive.

Comment: Servers, Active Directory, and Azure use the User's Login Credentials when logging on to a domain to access files. There is a password - it occurs when logging on to the domain. Your local NAS is simpler. You need to put in the NAS credentials as requested. I further recommend you do not put the password in the NET USE string as that is insecure.

Comment: So you have two domains?

Comment: Having something like Azure already working: Wouldn't it be easier to migrate the NAS content to it? Also, in `c:\users`, there is a "default" profile - that's used when new users login for the first time, it's a "template-directory". Maybe you can use that to make your program appear on different user logins?